# SVN commit Error "Commit can only commit to a single repository at a time."

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit, subclipse

I'm using an eclipse with "Subclipse" installed to commit my changes to a repository that located at my DropBox folder.

I've created a repository using Tortoise.My actual project sits in the root of repository folder but not in a trunk or branch or tag folders.

I successfully created,checked out and committed several times , but lately I've begun to receive an error on commit :

> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: E200007: Commit can only commit to a single repository at a time.
>   Are all targets part of the same working copy?
>   org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: E200007: Commit can only commit to a single repository at a time.
>   Are all targets part of the same working copy?

And nothing can be committed...
What causing this problem and how can it be resolved ???

Comment: Did you recently add any third party source by checking it out or extracting a zip file inside your repo? If so, you may have extra `.svn` folders that belong to that project that confuse subversion.

Comment: I checked out the project , and inside it I've created a new package with a new class in it.Does it counts ?

Comment: Nope...I've downloaded the project from repository on another computer,and recreated the repository.Now I think that a simple "clean" operation could help.But what done is done.

Answer (score 17):

This normally works:

right click on the project -> team -> cleanup / refresh

Answer (score 0):

For command line svn, I fixed this by running a `find ./ -name ".*"` to find those hidden files and maintain only the root `.svn` structure.